# remove chars from string that may show multiple times

Tags: javascript

I'm looking forward for a simple solution how to erase these array of chars from a specific string

`const ignoreMe = ['a', 'b', 'c'];`

so if my string contains one of these chars it will return it without them
example: "abcde" will return "de",
 * one of these chars may appear or not and may even appear multiple times so I need to handle all of these cases.

I was thinking about running on every char in my string and then to see if it's equal to one of them but I think it's too much, is there a simpler way to do it ?

thanks.

Comment: What would be wrong with `string.replace(/[abc]/g, '')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using array approach you can [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string into an array and use [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) then join that filtered array back into string

```js
var ignores = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var str ='abcde';

var res = str.split('').filter(function(char){
   return !ignores.includes(char)
}).join('')

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can pass the the chars to the regex pattern. See the below solution.

```js
var string = "abcde"
var result = string.replace(/^abc+/i, '')

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of single charecters, you can do something like this:

```js
let str = 'aaaxxxbbbyyyccc';
const ignoreMe = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const cleanStr = str.replace(new RegExp(`[${ignoreMe.join()}]`, 'g'), '');
console.log(cleanStr);
```